# Excel 2010 cannot paste into a form textbox

Tags: forms, excel, textbox, vba

I have a textbox within a frame on my form. A user wants to copy and paste data into this textbox, but they are unable to do so. They can copy but when they try a right click or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> nothing happens.

I've looked at the textbox properties and don't see anything that is preventing this. The data they are copying is Arial 10.  The textbox is formatted as Arial Regular 10.

Is there something on the form or frame that is preventing the paste feature from not working?

Thanks for the help....

Comment: Are there any new lines in the copied data? That may cause an issue, if so check the `MultiLine` segment is set to true

Comment: @Maldred...........Multiline has been set to True.  thanks

Comment: Not sure if that solved your problem or not, can you confirm?

Comment: @Maldred.....sorry...........that didn't help.  I still cannot paste into the textbox.  I can paste the data in Word.  then copy it from Word and at that point, I can paste it into the textbox

Comment: What about Notepad? When pasting in Notepad, are there any special characters that may have appeared in it?

Comment: Is the keyboard shortcut the culprit? Does right-click paste work? We should at least narrow down where the issue is.

Comment: @Maldred...........I pasted the data into Notepad and there seems to be some "white moise" behind the data I copied.  I'm not sure where that is coming from because if I hit F2 on that field, there is not after the data I'm copiying.......This stuff will make you crazy.......Neither Shortcut key or right click will paste in the textbox

Comment: @K.Davis............neither right click or shortcut will paste data in this textbox

Comment: You said it works fine when copying from Word... where are they originally copying this data from?

Comment: @freginold.........I'll have to check with the user.  I was copying something out of the datasheet within the macro and it wouldn't work with me.  My guess is they are copying from another workbook.  Just a guess.  I'll check with the user in the morning

Comment: @Shaves So you were copying from one cell to another when it wouldn't work?

Comment: @freginold............I was copying from a cell and trying to paste the contents into a text box in a user form.  CTRL + V and Right Click doesn't work.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be able to paste into a textbox in a frame, you have to first be in **Edit** mode:

- Right click on the textbox
- Hover over **Textbox Object**
- In the submenu, select **Edit**

[image]

Now you can change the text inside the box, including pasting text from other sources.

**UPDATE:**

When the textbox has focus, you can copy a cell's *value* into it, but not the reference to the cell itself. Click on the cell whose value you want to copy, then copy the text from the formula bar at the top of the screen and paste that into your textbox.

Comment: @freginold.........I tried that but it didn't work for me.  The textbox I'm referring to is in form.  We click a "search" button to open a user form.  The user is wanting to copy and paste from another source into that text box.  CRTL + V or right click doesn't do anything to the textbox

Comment: @Shaves If you click on the textbox first (to move the focus to it) and then try CTRL+V or right clicking to paste, does that work?

Comment: @freginold............When the user form opens, that textbox already has the focus.  The cursor is in the middle of the textbox and blinking.  I clicked on it, just to be sure, and CRTL + V doesn't paste anything.  I can start typing with the keyboard but the CTRL + V does nothing.  Thanks for your help......

Comment: @Shaves Are you trying a copy a *cell* or a *cell value*? Meaning, are you right-clicking on a cell and copying, or are you highlighting the text/data inside the cell and copying that?

Comment: @freginold............I'm selecting a cell and then using CTRL + C.  Thanks

Comment: @Shaves That could be your issue. If the textbox has focus, you should be able to copy a value into it, but not the reference to a cell.  Try clicking on the cell whose value you want to copy, then selecting and copying the text from the formula bar at the top of the screen and pasting that into your textbox.

Comment: @freginold............Thank you very much.  That did the trick.  You just made a user very happy.  Thanks again.........